# How make a query in Ionic 3 with firestore and show the datas in a list?

Tags: ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

im new in ionic 3, i was reading the documentation of firestore in the page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es-419, and i was trying to make a query but i can't, i dont understand so much, pleas someone helped to know how make a query in firebase.

in the code, i recive a email of a page and i want to use this email to delimited the datas, just show where the subfield of the collection by the same of the email that i recieve

```
this is the page where i was making the query:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';


export interface Rutina {
  id: String;
  dia: String;
  ejercicio: String;
  series: String;
  repeticiones:String;
  email:String;
}

export class RutinaejercicioPage {

  email;
  dia;
  db;
  private itemCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Rutina>;
  items: Observable<Rutina[]>;

  private itemsCollection2: AngularFirestoreCollection<Rutina>;
  items2: Observable<Rutina[]>

  private itemsCollection3: AngularFirestoreCollection<Rutina>;
  items3: Observable<Rutina[]>

  private itemsCollection4: AngularFirestoreCollection<Rutina>;
  items4: Observable<Rutina[]>

  private itemsCollection5: AngularFirestoreCollection<Rutina>;
  items5: Observable<Rutina[]>

  private itemsCollection6: AngularFirestoreCollection<Rutina>;
  items6: Observable<Rutina[]>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.email = this.navParams.get('email');
    console.log(this.email);

    if(this.dia == 'lunes'){
    this.itemCollection = this.db.collection("items").where("email", "==", this.email)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            return doc.data();
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });

    }
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RutinaejercicioPage');
  }



}

this is the html where i want to show the list:
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>rutinaejercicio</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list inset>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      {{item.}}
    </button>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

this image show my database:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has query to fetch list of any items. For an instance, below is a method which can be called to fetch a list of items from firestore with respect to the reference of the collection.

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsServiceProvider {

db: any;
collection: string = 'items';

constructor() {
  this.db = firebase.firestore();
}


getAllItemsByUserId(userId) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.db.collection(this.collection)
    .where('uid', '==', userId)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      let arr = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
        obj.id = doc.id;
        //obj.eventId = doc.id;
        arr.push(obj);
      });

      if (arr.length > 0) {
        resolve(arr);
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
        resolve(null);
      }
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      reject(error);
    });
   });
  }
 }

}
```

It could be called from any class as

```
this.itemsServiceProvider.getAllItemsByUserId(this.userId).then((e) => {
  this.listItems = e;
});
```

Then in the html, it could be listed using `ngFor` like below:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of listItems;let i = 'index'" style="padding-top: 20px;">
   <label class="control-label" >{{item.name}}</label>
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

That's it. If you've any doubts about Firestore queries, you can start from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)